# How to find element with non-static ID using Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to be able to send text to this text box element:

```
<form class="compose okform initialized">

    <div class="border"></div>
    <div id="message_9028519832635440005Container" class="inputcontainer textarea empty">
        <textarea class="clone" placeholder="Compose your message" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 21px; width: 417px; line-height: 18px; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 0px;" tabindex="-1"></textarea>
        <textarea id="message_9028519832635440005" placeholder="Compose your message" style="height: 39px;"></textarea>

        <span class="okform-feedback message empty" style="height: 0"></span>
        <div class="icon okicon"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="flatbutton" type="submit"></button>
    <div class="draft_message"></div>
    <label class="checkbox" for="enter_to_send_9028519832635440005"></label>

</form>
```

I'm not able to location the element by searching for part of the ID (the number after message_ is dynamically generated).

I've also tried this but I get an error saying "unknown error: cannot focus element":

```
var textBox = DriverActions.driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("inputcontainer"));
textBox[0].SendKeys("Why hello");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath using starts-with

```
var textBox= DriverActions.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//textarea[starts-with(@id,'message_')]"));
textBox.SendKeys("Why hello");
```

The reason that you are getting the error could be because by your selector you will end up getting a `div` instead of a `textBox` that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css

```
.inputcontainer.textarea.empty>textarea:nth-child(1)
```

I assumed you want the first text area box with `placeholder="Compose your message"`
if so, you can also use the following cssSelector

```
[placeholder='Compose your message'][class='clone']
```

Partial search with *id* is also possible. Assuming the **Container** part of the div's id is unique and static, you can do the following

```
[id$='Container']>textarea:nth-child(1)
```

On the other hand, if you want the second textarea just simply change the child index

```
[id$='Container']>textarea:nth-child(2)
```

And, here is the implementation

```
By byCss = By.CssSelector("[id$='Container']>textarea:nth-child(1)");
IWebElement textBox = driver.FindElement(byCss);
textBox.SendKeys("Why hello");
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot from your explanation.  But it says "element not visible"  I tried using the method the poster below suggested and it worked for me.

Comment: @MJJ_PDX Which one returns *element not visible*?